# How to get the name of the UI control that kicked off the event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I have the following code that implements 2 [jQuery sliders](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#wheelLeft").slider({ value: 50, min: -100, max: 100, slide: handleSlide });
        $("#wheelRight").slider({ value: -10, min: -100, max: 100, slide: handleSlide });
    });

    function handleSlide(event, ui) {
        $("#lblInfo").text(ui.id + ':' + ui.value);
    }
</script>
```

As you see, both sliders generate a slide event which is handled by `handleSlide` function. Inside the `handleSlide` function, I can get the value of the slider by calling ui.value, but how do i know which slider actually generated the event?

I've tried ui.id, ui.name and some others that seemed logical, but they all come back as undefined.  How do I get actual name of its CSS implementation (e.g. either #wheelRight or #wheelLeft)?

Thanks.

Comment: What about `event.srcElement || event.target`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try wrapping ui.handle

```
function handleSlide(event, ui) {
  $("#lblInfo").text( $(ui.handle).attr("id") + ':' + ui.value);
}
```

**Edit**: Oops, that returns the "a" element. This should return the parent element id:

```
$(ui.handle).parent().attr('id')
```

Comment: Nope.  $(ui.handle).attr("id") returns blank.

Comment: $(ui.handle).parent().attr('id')

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the id selectors (or any arguments of your choice) directly to your handler function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#wheelLeft").slider({
        value: 50, min: -100, max: 100,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            handleSlide(event, ui, "#wheelLeft");
        }
    });
    $("#wheelRight").slider({
        value: -10, min: -100, max: 100,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            handleSlide(event, ui, "#wheelRight");
        }
    });
});

function handleSlide(event, ui, idSelector)
{
    $("#lblInfo").text(idSelector);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function handleSlide(event, ui) {
    var sender = event.srcElement || event.target;
     $("#lblInfo").text(ui.id + ':' + ui.value);
}
```

The `sender` should contain the raw element that triggered the event.

Comment: Nope.  var sender = event.srcElement || event.target; returns the path of the file.